# How to return a data from Express request by doing asynchronous sqlite3 queries within a loop?

Tags: node.js, express, node-sqlite3

I am very new to **NodeJS** and **Express** and struggling to use `sqlite3` 
module.

Let's assume I have a database with 2 tables: **cars**, **car_details**. 
This is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
router.get('/get-car-info', (req, res) => {
    let car_details = [];
    let sql = '';
    let cars = ['audi', 'bmw', 'benz', 'honda', 'toyota];

    cars.forEach(car => {
        sql = `SELECT * FROM car_details WHERE name=${car}`;

        db.get(sql, function(err, data) {
            if (!err) {       
                car_details.push(data);
            }
        });
    });

    res.json({ 'success': true, 'cars': car_details });
});
```

This is a basic example but its enough to describe the problem.
Since `db.get` is async request, by the time the loop is done, the response is empty since it gets called before queries are finished.

If there was just one query then fine, I would send the response within `callback` but not sure how to achieve that when having a loop/recursion situation.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where in` clause to get data for more details visit [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-where/)

```
router.get('/get-car-info', (req, res) => {
      let car_details = [];
      let cars = ['audi', 'bmw', 'benz', 'honda', 'toyota];

      function inParam(sql, arr) {
        return sql.replace('?#', arr.map(() => '?').join(','))
      }

      db.get(inParam('SELECT * FROM car_details WHERE name in (?#)', car), car, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(data)
          car_details.push(data);
        }
      });
 });
```

Comment: The main question is about how to handle sqlite3 queries within a loop. As I mentioned it is a very simple example, but you might need to do another query within a query after getting car details...

Comment: alright.. then you need to return db.get and use promise.all to wait for all the responses..

Comment: can you please give an example code on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.. but please verify the car_details result , i am hoping each `db.get` request return data directly..

```
   router.get('/get-car-info', async (req, res) => {
        let sql = '';
        let cars = ['audi', 'bmw', 'benz', 'honda', 'toyota];    
        let car_details = await Promise.all(cars.map(car => {
            sql = `SELECT * FROM car_details WHERE name=${car}`;
            return db.get(sql);
        }));

        res.json({ 'success': true, 'cars': car_details });
    });
```

Comment: does not seem to work, I think I have to use a different module `better-sqlite3`